# How do I specify a type object that must be of another type?

Tags: typescript

I want to force a type object to satisfy a type pattern like so:

```
type Color = string
type Intent = 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'error'

// This doesn't work
type IntentColors: Record<Intent, Color> = {
  primary: '#fff' | 'white';
  secondary: '#000' | 'black';
  error: '#ff0000' | 'pink';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Record<Intent, Color>` is a named object type whose keys are statically known at compile time, you can have an `interface` *extend* it:

```
interface IntentColors extends Record<Intent, Color> {
  primary: '#fff' | 'white';
  secondary: '#000' | 'black';
  error: '#ff0000' | 'pink';
}
```

This is concise, and it will warn if you try to narrow one of the existing properties with a bad value type, like:

```
interface BadIntentColors extends Record<Intent, Color> { // error!
  primary: '#fff' | 'white';
  secondary: number;  // oops
  error: '#ff0000' | 'pink';
}
```

If you don't mention `primary`, `secondary`, or `error` in the declaration, they will stay `string`, because that's how interface extension works (`interface Bar extends Foo {}` means that `Bar` has the same properties as `Foo`). This could be a problem if you misspell a property, since the compiler will just add it as a new property, without warning:

```
interface UncaughtIntentColors extends Record<Intent, Color> {
  primairy: '#fff' | 'white';
  secondery: '#000' | 'black';
  erorr: '#ff0000' | 'pink';
} // no errors
```

It's up to you to decide whether the conciseness of interface extension is worth this possible stumbling point.

---

A different approach is to add a helper type alias you can use to verify your constraint:

```
type Extends<T, U extends T> = void;
```

The `Extends` type doesn't evaluate to anything interesting (it's always `void`), but if you write `Extends<A, B>` then there will be an error if `B` is not assignable to `A`.

So you can first define `IntentColors` without mentioning `Record<Intent, Color>`:

```
type IntentColors = {
  primary: '#fff' | 'white';
  secondary: '#000' | 'black';
  error: '#ff0000' | 'pink';
}
```

and then check it using `Extends`:

```
type TestIntentColors = Extends<Record<Intent, Color>, IntentColors>; // no error
```

If you make any kind of mistake:

```
type BadIntentColors = {
  primary: '#fff' | 'white';
  secondery: '#000' | 'black'; // oops
  error: '#ff0000' | 'pink';
}
```

It should be caught:

```
type TestBadIntentColors = Extends<Record<Intent, Color>, BadIntentColors>; // error!
// -----------------------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//  Property 'secondary' is missing in type 'BadIntentColors' 
// but required in type 'Record<Intent, string>'.
```

This might be closer to the behavior you're looking for, but again it's up to you to decide if this behavior is worth the verbosity of adding a helper type alias and an separate "check" line of code.

---

Okay, hope one of those helps.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=1&ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGzgJygXigZ2MglgOwHMAoUSKASX2AmvSgHIw8BbAQ2RAagB9HMIAYzj4AJhy69GEZMhQNixfGxYRMYNoOgBRAB418mXCKgBvRVCgEayAGaboVA8HhJkmKBH21RHgEpCKKIAPE60wAA0sIgoAHxmxJaWzLjsnABcjADEtrncfAwA7gAWuDQMANyJSQLCYhKZDFkADK35jABGCJoA1pXVljJyyI05tq1tUkwEfVWWAL4WVtQy9lpQAEJsomHUrigeXga+UAHCyCG7kdFu8aZQAPQPnrIoAIQDUClpIKO5tu0iqVynMaoF6hkoPgAK4sDoyUGDV4jbK5CbNQFgGb9BZLayrBxQACq+EEbGhhGKwCu+3cnm8Yn8gQuoRW1CitLun2+bFwkKa-0BJTKEBxYLqohkv2yE0BXV6YqRKBRAvGsqmWPws2q80ez3wcBew0wikWShUag06wAajJcLYQAlLGQdAzfMEACpRIn044eD3xDAANzguFEVWqLsobJcMTpGHMSS+rAaqLyU2FIM+tRE4n5LUmBXlgm1SaGKD+asLjE1pagi2d4GgHrU1JjtI8GD0fuCZyCrOcHLjsSiNLjmFiFT1UMN5eQSyjWx27fH9ETSR5+cFGeBosRWHBkvz6qL3RLlWncDgYBNZeRlfRmOxoIbUCjLewS7Hbk7UG7PkwXtmUuGMh1uKIvxXH9J2nOcPksJ4oAAWhQ1C0PQjDMKw7CsPiAA-AjCKI4jqkQqAAAU5EgZBQH4Q8JG4XAPBYJijCIZY3ybRhIOcDtuFI54OmhYAoGQCAAEdoT5CBRA4qMGD7FkriibA8CIWIGAAOmIeYgA)